# Maven not running Test

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, selenium

I created a new maven project in Eclipse that runs simple test by using both HtmlUnitDriver and FirefoxDriver to pull up a web page and check the title on the page. When I run maven command mvn test this is all that I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ my-app ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.049s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 31 11:53:38 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the same Maven command in Eclipse, it shows the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Andrew/Development/code/my-app/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.878s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 31 11:58:23 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my pom.xml for those who want to check if that may be the issue:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.39.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <type>pom</type>
     </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Try running a specific test. `mvn -Dtest=<test_class_name> test`

Comment: How is your test class named?

Comment: Added "test" into my class name and it worked.

Comment: Please show the code of your test, at least the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean to add `org.apache.maven.surefire` as a POM dependency under `<dependencies>`?

Most usages of the Surefire plugin are configured under the `<pluginManagement>` section:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```