# How do I run MRUnit tests using mvn test command like JUnit tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, mapreduce, mrunit

I am able to run the MRUnit tests from eclipse by right clicking the project and clicking Run as JUnit test, but when I run the same MRUnit test program using the mvn test command on the command line, I get the following output with no errors:

```
...
Running com.bah.ossem.WordcountMRUnitTest
Configuring TestNG with:        
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configuator@428aaed5
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.727 
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
...
```

Furthermore, I can run normal JUnit tests with the mvn test command just fine.

Comment: So basically other JUnit test cases are executing but MRUnit related test cases are not running? What is command you are using?

Comment: Is it a Unit 4 test (with @Test annotation) or JUnit 3 test (extends TestCase)?

Comment: @abhishekbafna Yes, other JUnit test cases are executing but not MRUnit ones.

Comment: I use the mrunit for mapreduce test cases along with maven. Are you test cases annotated with @Test?

Comment: @StefanBirkner It is Unit 4 test with (@Test annotations) I can put the code but I figured since it was working in eclipse, the code is okay.

Comment: @abhishekbafna I am using the command: mvn test. Do I have to add anything to the command for the mrunit test methods to run?

Comment: Thanks @abhishekbafna I was able to find the answer and I posted it below. Maybe you could explain why the answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this to my pom.xml file:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer came from: [Maven not running Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485744/maven-not-running-test)