# Maven build project successfully but no test execution

Tags: selenium

I have created two different project in eclipse, one of them is working fine but another one is having issue:

**console.xml:**
[image: console.xml]

**pom.xml:**
[image: pom.xml]

Comment: more details would are needed like, whats the test farmework? what is the config is pom.xml? etc

Comment: I am using testng framework, you can find two images with my question

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485744/maven-not-running-test) and [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) might help you.

Comment: I'm not able to understand , what the question is? Could you please share more details?